# В чем различие между return {veiwName} и return redirect:/

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

Spring Boot MVC, Controller, RequestMapping указывает на файл index как /.
Метод

```
@PostMapping
public String add(@RequestParam(value = "name")  String name) {
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

может возвращать как имя файла return "index"; так и return "redirect:/"; приложение работает одинаково.
Не могу понять, в чем разница.

Comment: В том, что будет отображаться в полле ввода пользователя. В одном случае это полный редирект и там будет новая ссылка, во втором пользователь как бы останется на той же странице, но увидить другую. Не помню какой когда

Comment: Непонятно вот это  "пользователь как бы останется на той же странице, но увидить другую."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

когда Вы говорите `return "index";` Вы указываете имя `view`, которая будет использована шаблонизатором для заполненения модели и рендеринга `имя_view.html` страницы, таким образом происходит следующая цепочка: `запрос к контроллеру -> отрисовка страницы.`

В случае  `return "redirect:/";` вы производите редирект в рут `"/"`, который в Вашем случае является методом контроллера `add`, который так же возвращает index.html, только цепочка в этом случае будет уже следующая: `запрос к контроллеру -> редирект -> запрос к контроллеру -> отрисовка страницы`
Таким образом метод add будет вызван два раза в случае `redirect`.
Если хочется чуть лучше понимать как работает MVC попробуйте прочитать эту статью:
https://habr.com/ru/post/461965/